# Assign result of conditional expression to environment variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I'd like to store the result of a conditional expression in an environment variable.

I tried:

```sh
C=$([ "$A" = "$B" ])
```

but the value of `$C` after running that is an empty string.

I could of course do something like this:

```sh
if [ "$A" = "$B" ]
then
  C=1
else
  C=0
fi
```

but I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: For the record, "true" and "false" there are no different from any other string such as "you" and "me". Also bash is not programming language like Java or so, therefore you expectation that it has builtin facility that automagically converts a boolean type value (which isn't exactly a thing in bash either) to a string was never real.

Comment: Besides, `$(command)` expands the what `command` outputs to stdout, and `[ 'A' == 'B' ]` doesn't output anything anyway, so.

Comment: @TomYan I'm aware that environment variables are strings. And I'm aware that `[ 'A' == 'B' ]` does not output anything which is why I asked the question. So to clarify, I'd like `$C` to be a string that is either 'true' or 'false' based on the result of the expression.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the simplest solution is this:

```sh
C=$(! [ "$A" = "$B" ]; echo $?)
```

This just negates the exit code of the test command and assigns it to `$C`.

Comment: you may as well edit your question and answer additionally by replacing the single quotes with double quotes; while neither of them are necessary in your showcase, most likely you would want something like `[ "$X" = "$Y" ]` at the end of the day, in which case single-quotes will change the meaning completely.

Comment: @TomYan Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Use an expression like this:

```
variable=$([ "A" == "B" ] && echo "true" || echo "false")
```

Comment: This results in an error: `bash: 'A' == 'B' ? 1 : 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'A' == 'B' ? 1 : 0 ")`. I think the string comparison is the problem because `variable=$(( 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0 ))` works.

Comment: Can't test here: try double-quotes.

Comment: Double quotes work! Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that now it always results in 1 (with `variable=$(( "A" == "B" ? 1 : 0 ))`), no matter if the strings are equal or not.

Comment: You don't need any kind of quotes when there's nothing to expand or escape. As for why this doesn't work, it's because `(( A == B ))` is pretty much equivalent to `(( 0 == 0 ))`, for it's doing arithmetic: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html (which is probably also why only double quotes are expected / allowed, for parameter expansion).

Comment: The problem is that the ternary `?` operator only works for numbers. I rewrote my answer for strings.